# com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Login failed for user 'root'. ClientConnectionId<lots of stuff here>

Tags: java, sql-server-2008, jdbc

I am trying to access SQL Server 2008 through java code, but I am getting the following error:

`com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Login failed for user
'root'.ClientConnectionId`

Why is this happening and how to fix it ?

Comment: Post related code. It seems something related to userid/password.

Comment: SQL Server doesn't typically have a user named 'root'.  Is this something that was ported from MySQL to SQL Server but someone just forgot to change the usernames and passwords?

Comment: Yes, the code was ported from MySQL to SQL.

Comment: But, I created a new user and password and fixed that issue. Code is working.